# When to close mongoose connection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I just started to learn Node.js, this is the code I wrote.
in /module, i have a db.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error);
db.once('open',function(){

});
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
//If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  mongoose.connection.close(function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

exports.db = mongoose;
```

and a module user.js

```
var mongoose = require('./db').db;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: "String",
    email: "String",
    password: "String"
});
exports.User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema);
```

Then in the app.js

```
var User = require('./module/user').User;
var user001 = new User({
    name:"user001",
    email:"user001@email.com",
    password:"password001"
});

user001.save(function(err,result){
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(result);
});
```

When I run app.js, after the save, the process does not exit, I know it is because mongoose is still connected.My question is how can I automatically close it when process exit? (I know I have to use mongose.connect.close() to close it, but where should I put this in the code?)

Comment: What process are you talking about? Even if your `save` method returns your server will still be running.

Comment: Rohit,What I meant by that is when I run node app.js, it shows the result after the save,but after that the app does not exit. I have to do a Ctrl+C to terminate the app. Is this a right behaviour for node.js that I have to manually terminate the app?

Comment: how do you call the `save` method? I assume you have started some kind of http server app, this is a correct behavior.

Comment: Rohit, I am not calling any http server, i am just writing a console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you have meant with, when you save the user model you should disconnect from Mongo DB. Because in the code above you are not killing the Process when the Model is saved, you are just logging the result from it.

As for the listener on 'SIGINT' event, you should be able to close the connection after you kill the Node process from the terminal by hitting CTRL-C command.

What I always do when writing an App is a add a couple of more listeners to the process.

```js
process.once('SIGUSR2', function() {
 shutdown(process.exit);
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
 shutdown(process.exit);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
 shutdown(process.exit); 
});

process.on('exit', function() {
 shutdown();
});

function shutdown(callback) {
  // shutdown connections
  callback && callback();
}
```